# And operator && equivalent in <exec command>

Tags: msbuild

So I am aware that && operator can be used to chain commands. However in the my build process
 does not work.

Is there an equivalent as I know you can use the || operator here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want this:

```bash
echo foo && echo bar
```

Then use this:

```xml
<Exec Command="echo foo %26%26 echo bar" />
```

Reference: [Escape special characters in MSBuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-escape-special-characters-in-msbuild?view=vs-2022).

Answer (score 0):

This does not work for me:

```
<Exec Command="echo foo && echo bar" />

<Exec Command="echo foo %26%26 echo bar" />
```

This works for me:

```
<Exec Command="echo foo &amp;&amp; echo bar" />

<Exec Command="echo foo ; echo bar" />
```